# Mongoid update_attributes creating new referenced document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, database-relations

I'm having trouble using `update_attributes` with referenced documents.  I've reduced my problem to a simple example that AFAICT should work, but doesn't:

```
class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :submissions, :autosave => true
end

class Submission
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :account
end

a = Account.new
a.save!

s = Submission.new
s.update_attributes({"account" => {"id" => a.id}})
s.save!

a.id == s.account.id  # false
```

The call to `update_attributes` is creating a new blank `Account` object instead of referencing the existing one that I'm telling it to use.  What's going on?

**UPDATE**

To be clear, I'm trying to process an HTML form in an `update` action which adds an `Account` to a `Submission`.  I understand there are other ways to link these documents by writing specific code.  But the normal rails way should allow me to use an HTML form to update the documents this way, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML form to make "account_id" not "account[id]" then it starts working:

```
s.update_attributes({"account_id" => a.id})
s.save!

a.id == s.account.id  # true
a == s.account # true
```

Very odd what it's doing.  Maybe mongoid bug?

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way to add `s` to `a`. What you want to do is this:

```
a = Account.new
a.submissions << Submission.new
a.save!
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work, but it's not what I want to do.  I updated the question to point out that I'm trying to add an `Account` to a `Submission` through a form.

Comment: You should still save the parent object, not the child. (Based on the models you gave, you aren't "adding an `Account` to a `Submission`." `Account`s hold `Submission`s, not the other way around.) Are you using a Rails form gem to handle the relations? Maybe if you post some code from your `update` method I could help.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but the `Submission` document has the `account_id` field in mongo, not the other way around.  I should be able to update a `Submission` and point it to an `Account` even if I only have read-only access to `Account` objects.  My `update` method is pure vanilla scaffold, and the HTML form is posting what's in the question.